# Bound the number of red edges in a red-blue coloring of $K_{n}$ such that no two red triangles share an edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Denote by $K_n$ the complete graph with $n$ vertices. Let $RE(n)$ be maximum number of red edges in a red-blue coloring of $K_{n}$ such that no two red triangles share an edge. I want to show that $RE(n)=o(n^2)$, or preferably the stronger result that I suspect: $RE(n)\leq O(n^{3/2})$.

The original problem: Show that in any red-blue coloring of $K_n$ such that no two red triangles share an edge, there exists a $K_{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor}$ containing no red-triangles. I reduced this problem to the problem above.

Comment: A complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$ (if $n$ is even) and $K_{(n-1)/2,(n+1)/2}$ (if $n$ is odd) have respectively
$n^2/4$ edges and $(n^2-1)/4$ edges. So the number of edges in such graph is $O(n^2)$.
There are no triangles in such a graph, hence there are no edges that are  included of two triangles. Thus it seems that your statement is wrong.

Comment: I see and I agree with you. My reduction of the original problem turned it into an false statement, and the original problem holds because of some uneven distributions of red triangles in the $K_k$'s. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: It can be proved that the number of edges of a graph in which each edge enters no more than one triangle does not exceed $n^2/4$ as for a graph without triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting task.
Here we formulate a monochromatic version of this problem equivalent to the color one.

> **Theorem.** If $G$ is a graph of order $n$ in which each edge enters at most one triangle,  then $G$ contains an induced triangle-free
> subgraph of order at least $\sqrt{2n}$.

Here is a brief proof of this theorem.

Denote $q=[\sqrt{2n}]$ and assume that $n\geq3$.
We will say that a subset of vertices $S\subset V(G)$ has no triangles if $G[S]$ is an induced triangle-free subgraph.
We must find a subset without triangles containing $\geq q$ vertices.

1. Let the graph $G$ have a vertex $v$ such that $\deg(v)=q-1$.

Let $N_G(v)$ be all neighbors of $v$ and $u\notin N_G(v)\cup\{v\}$ (at $n\geq3$ we have $q<n$).
The subset $N_G(v)\cup\{u\}$ has no triangles and $|N_G(v)\cup\{u\}|=q$.

2. Let $\deg(v)\leq q-2$ for each vertex $v\in V(G)$.

Now let $S\subset V(G)$ be a maximal subset without triangles and $|S|=s$.

Since $\deg(x)\leq q-2$ for each vertex $x\in S$, the number of edges of the graph $H=G[S]$ is at most $s(q-2)/2$.
Because each edge enters at most one triangle we have
$$
|T|\leq|E(H)|\leq s(q-2)/2. 
$$
If $|S|+|T|<n$, then there exists a vertex $v\in V(G)$ and $v\notin S\cup T$
and the set $S\cup\{v\}$ has no triangles. This contradicts the maximality of $S$.

Thus $|S|+|T|\geq n$. So
$$
n\leq|S|+|T|\leq s+s(q-2)/2=sq/2\ \Rightarrow\ s\geq2n/q\geq\sqrt{2n}.
$$

This is what we needed to prove.

Comment: This is really clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by result of this problem. If you let {$A_i$} be the family of triangle vertex sets of $G$, you'll find this two problems are same.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h48298p305430

It was problem from Romanian IMO team selection test, 1999.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2025147)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title question is that $\operatorname{RE}(3)=3$ and $\operatorname{RE}(n)=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ for $n\ne3$.

To save typing let $f(n)=\operatorname{RE}(n)$. It is easy to verify that $f(3)=3$ and $f(n)=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ for $n=1,2,4$. Moreover, it's easy to see that $f(n)\ge\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ for all $n$; just color the edges of $K_n$ so that the spanning subgraph formed by the red edges is a complete bipartite graph $K_{\lceil n/2\rceil,\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$. We will prove by induction that $f(n)\le\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ for $n\gt4$.

First, by counting in two ways the pairs $(e,v)$ consisting of a red edge $e$ and a vertex $v$ not incident with $e$, we see that $f(n)\cdot(n-2)\le nf(n-1)$, *i.e.*,
$$f(n)\le\left\lfloor\frac n{n-2}f(n-1)\right\rfloor$$
for $n\gt2$.

For the inductive step, let $n\gt4$ and assume that $f(n-1)\le\lfloor(n-1)^2/4\rfloor$; we have to show that $f(n)\le\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$. We consider two cases depending on the parity of $n$.

**Case 1.** $n=2k$ and $f(n-1)=f(2k-1)\le\lfloor(2k-1)^2/4\rfloor=k(k-1)$. Then
$$f(n)=f(2k)\le\frac{2k}{2k-2}k(k-1)=k^2=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor.$$
**Case 2.** $n=2k+1$ and $f(n-1)=f(2k)\le\lfloor(2k)^2/4\rfloor=k^2$. Then
$$f(n)=f(2k+1)\le\left\lfloor\frac{2k+1}{2k-1}k^2\right\rfloor\le k^2+k=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor$$
since
$$\frac{2k+1}{2k-1}k^2\lt k^2+k+1.$$